# Regarding pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, pointers, math, printing

I'm trying to print the address a pointer is holding in C. Would I use %d or %p for the format specifier? And are all pointer addresses ints? In this youtube video, I thought that was the case but when I tried to code something, it would not compile unless I used %p. Also, isn't i_ptr+1 supposed to be the memory address i_ptr holds + 4 because an int is 4 bytes? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTttg85xsbo

Thankyou!!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int *i_ptr);
int main() {
  int i[5];
  test(i);
  return 0;
}

void test(int *i_ptr) {
  printf("%d\n", i_ptr);
  printf("%d\n", i_ptr + 1);
}
```

~

Comment: Use `%p` for printing pointers.

Comment: And also cast to `void*`.

Comment: It might also be useful to know that `*(pointer + i)` is equivalent to `pointer[i]`.

Comment: why does it need to be void*? @Ani I already knew that. Thanks though.

Comment: And you are correct that a pointer (or an address) is an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), they are however not `int`. There's a difference between the concept of integers, and the type `int`.

Comment: you have to `printf("%p\n",(void *)i_ptr)`. same for others.

Comment: @KevinCheng Because that's what the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function is specified to handle.

Comment: @KevinCheng `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

Comment: @Jayesh This is what I get. 0xbfa2187c
0xbfa21880

Comment: I want it to print integers. Am i supposed to type something else? If i use %d it'll print what I want, but with a compiler warning. Thanks.

Comment: 0xbfa2187c is an integer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a compiler that supports C99, you can use the type `uintptr_t` to hold the value of a pointer. However, since its size is not specified by compiler and there isn't a `printf` specifier for such a type, you have to experiment with  using `"%d"`, `"%ld"` and `"%lld"` to make things work. I want to emphasize that ***it is not portable code***.

The following code worked for me, using gcc 4.8.2 on a 64-bit Linux machine with `-std=c99`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void test(int *i_ptr);

int main() {
   int i[5];
   test(i);
   return 0;
}

void test(int *i_ptr) {
   uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)i_ptr;
   printf("%ld\n", p);
   p = (uintptr_t)(i_ptr+1);
   printf("%ld\n", p);
}
```

With the following output from a sample run.

```
140735074589984
140735074589988
```

**Update**

The format specifier `"%td"` is meant to be used for `ptrdiff_t`. It's more likely that it will work for `uintptr_t` as well.